# Are there any words in German that are never to be used in polite conversation?

Tags: politeness, sociolinguistics, political-correctness, insult, taboos

#### Preface

As most British English speakers know, there are three words never to be uttered in polite conversation:

- The C-Word
- The N-Word
- The F-Word

Which grows to a list of seven words in American English, of which the funniest is *toilet* which should be commonly referred to as:

- Bathroom (No, I don't wan to take a bath...)
- Restroom (No, I don't want to rest...)
- Washroom (No, I don't want to do any laundry...)

So **I'm not talking about using a particular word offensively**: Any word can ultimately be used offensively, even *nice:*

> Der einzige Vorteil den Sie haben ist, dass Sie ein *netter* Mensch sind!

#### Actual Question

Are there German words that are **all by themselves** so offensive that they should never be used in polite conversation (even jokingly)?

If there would be any: Please be so kind as to give a list with a short description or a link to a dictionary.

#### Motivation

1. I’m neither a native German nor a native English speaker. And, in Britain, I was called by one of my employees *for years* (warning: unspeakable English expression):

   > "You silly cunt..."

   It took me another ten years or so to find out that this word is in the top-3 list of 'unspeakable words'. Instead of the explanation I was given (by the offending person, obviously) that

   > One man calling another man that word when no women are present, is extremely funny!

   (which it isn’t; he was just showing off in front of whichever male was standing around us at the time that *he could get away with this*.)
2. I want to avoid being the Harry Potter of the group and saying *Voldemort* and everyone around me cringing...
3. I know a lot of offensive words in German already, but I don't know if there are any *unspeakable* terms.

Comment: Discussions about the English language and answers-in-comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82978/discussion-on-question-by-fabby-are-there-any-words-in-german-that-are-never-to). Please use comments only for their [intended purpose](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: **Moderator’s notice:** I know, it’s tempting, but please refrain from illustrating your point by using deliberately offensive/bad language outside of a quote. The benefits in terms of funniness or enlightenment are just not outweighed by the risk of being blatantly misunderstood.

Comment: [Meta discussion](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/off-topic-or-not) about the on-topicness of this question.

Comment: I think "Motivation 1" (which I won't repeat here due to previous moderation decisions) would fly perfectly well in Australia, and as someone who lives near Australia I'm a bit confused why it had to be spoilered.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is a fundamental [cultural](http://www.bbc.com/culture/story/20150306-how-to-swear-around-the-world) difference between official American dogma and German everyday word usage.

You might take the stance that in German conversation people despise [profanities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profanity) as much as Americans do. If you avoid the same type of words in German you will not cause much consternation. Politeness is really based on largely the same contexts that those words describe: sexual, bodily functions, race or religion might be avoided (altogether) to stay polite. One example list which also contains a lot of very mild expressions and examples that not many German speakers might find really offensive at all is [German Words to Avoid: A Special Slang Glossary](https://www.thoughtco.com/german-words-to-avoid-special-slang-4071486) (take enough grains of salt when reading it).

But if you use those types of words in German, it will usually not be that much of a concern in German speaking countries.

Let's take a look at a *very* frequent example: *Scheiße*

The Cambridge dictionary lists all translations for this word and phrases containing it as "[offensive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shit)", which probably means: very strong word, do not use if you can't handle the magical power that comes with it.

If we look up *Scheiße* in German dictionaries like [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Scheisze) or [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Schei%C3%9Fe), we see just a factual explanation of the meaining and maybe the attribute *"derb"* (~crass, coarse, crude etc. – *but not rude*).

If you look at [George Carlins "Seven dirty words"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_dirty_words) there were and are feeble attempts to establish such a code on German airwaves as well. It didn't succeed. When on American public TV such a word is beeped out, you will hear German hosts reprimand the speaker of such words with "Na, aber! Wir sind hier…" or the audience making a Hohoho-like noise. Most of the time: that's it.

[Looking for words](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&ei=cCaVW9nbHom4sQGTy6zwBQ&q=worte%20die%20man%20vermeiden%20sollte&) to avoid in German you will find only tips for self presentation/business settings. The equivalent for "dirty words" or [*schmutzige Wörter*](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=schmutzige%20w%C3%B6rter&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) are mostly those vulgar or kinky words used to spice up life between the sheets.

One reason for all these subtle and not so subtle [differences](https://www.german-way.com/how-to-tell-when-germans-are-really-being-rude-versus-just-being-german/) start to be entrenched on a very fundamental level and quite early on.

> As a form of offensive behaviour and verbal aggression, the use of vulgar language is also a subject of educational consideration.
>
> In German-language parent guides, the understanding of the fascination with children exerted by swear words and "strong language" prevails as well as the need to vent pent-up frustration and the conviction that children benefit if they occasionally cross borders.
>
> In English-speaking countries, however, profanity (= vulgar expression), swearing and cursing (= swearing) as well as name-calling (= insulting) are regarded as expressions of a lack of respect for one's fellow human beings and thus as serious behavioural problems for which various countermeasures are proposed in the relevant guidebook literature.
> [WP: Vulgärsprache](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulg%C3%A4rsprache)

Coming back to the example chosen you will hear very often little children learning the rules to correct grown-ups they overheard violating those rules they were just taught with: *"Scheiße sagt man nicht!"* Thereby repeating the offensive act. And without much success for altering the behaviour of the adult, usually.

Using *Vulgärsprache* does not carry such a drastic social punishment in German. But it can mark you as quite low class.

To summarise: if *you* want to be *really* polite in German conversation, just follow the English rules you already know. But don't worry as much as to censor yourself and do not be overly surprised to hear words that Americans might feel are hyper-offensive in normal speech.

Of course, one constant remains the same over time. [Don't mention the war!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Germans) Or, more seriously: [Beware of Nazi Words](https://abcnews.go.com/International/story?id=4227660&page=1). There are some [taboos](https://www.goethe.de/en/spr/mag/20375829.html) to better observe. It's not so easy to offend a German by using just a word ('This is X'). But if directing such a word *at* a person ('You are X') it is easily perceived as offensive.

Comment: I second that, especially the _war_ thing and even more when it comes to expressions either introduced or abused by the Nazi regime. They are usually _not_ to be said.

Comment: I downvoted because "Don't mention the war" is not true anymore imho. Obviously you don't start small talk with "So, you Germans are pretty good at starting wars, am I right?" But you also would not start small talk with an american with a "Hey, so you are pretty good at killing Indians, am I right?". The war is not taboo anymore. If you talk for hours with a person, than there is nothing wrong with also talking about history. A problem is also that many non-germans are uneducated about the subject and Germans are tired of hearing myths like "Well at least Hitler built the Autobahn, right?".

Comment: @problemofficer While I can't agree with your assessment, I really appreciate that you explained your vote. Thank you.

Comment: You cannot avoid *Nazi words*, because the Nazis did not coin too many words on their own. Instead, they took expressions already used and gave them a new meaning. And this, they did plentiful and by purpose. Euphemisms make great propaganda.

Comment: Uh, and I think with **one thousand** "taboo" words in that moronic Nazi dictionary, it should be possible to write a decent story. One had to drop in some *ist* and a few *aber* but that's only for painting the picture right.

Comment: **@problemofficer** "Don't mention the war" is linked to a hilarious Fawlty towers episode that most non-German speaking will recognise, so it actually adds value to the answer.  **LanglanC** Danke Schön, akzeptiert und aufgewertet. Nur weiß Ich dass ich in Deutschland nicht für Harry Potter gehalten werden sollte!

Comment: I upvoted and much of this answer mirrors an [earlier comment of mine](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46853#comment113334_46853). Yet, I am not convinced of the final paragraph. First, lists of nazi vocabulary like the one linked above typically list quite a bit more than what is commonly avoided due to its historical background and thus are not a good reference. Case in point, the word "Selektion" mentioned early on in that article is a frequently used term in German computer science and no-one would think twice about it. Second, even for terms that are unmistakably rude and ...

Comment: ... that should indeed never be *used* to express what they mean, there is typically no expectation of any masking when talking *about* them. For instance, [this recent news article](https://www.zeit.de/politik/deutschland/2018-09/antisemitismus-josef-schuster-attacke-chemnitz-zentralrat-der-juden) provides a verbatim quotation of a reported insult towards Jewish people by neonazis, rather than using euphemisms like "J-word". In that respect, I think while some words can be *very* rude and highly frowned upon in German, the notion of an absolute "unspeakability" does not exist.

Comment: I'll not downvote since overall the answer is OK, but on the "don't mention the war" thing I'll have to agree with @problemofficer. Sure, if you are deliberately being an asshole and trying to offend like the "comedian" you linked to, you can very easily turn the conversation bad by "mentioning the war". So what. I could be similarly offensive by dressing like the British Queen and taking a piss on a little child. Context and intent matters. Either way, there's people even in Germany who find Cleese's pranks, including the Stupid Nazi jokes, funny despite their low niveau.

Comment: *Falwthy towers* is right on the spot. In the end, the Germans in the hotel are mostly offended by the low niveau of the continous Nazi references. *SEY ARE BORING AND DIS IS NOT FUNNY.*

Comment: Can't help but notice that I really should have heeded my own advice. Don't mention the war! Or Nazis.   ;)

Comment: From some of the reactions about "low level Nazi jokes", ISTM that indeed, Cleese was exactly right about "Don't mention the war" . Cleese made this for British TV and there and then (only a few decades after WWII), I'm sure most viewers found it funny and true and even in many other countries, e.g. Netherlands, Belgium, France, etc., people would agree: those days (mid and late seventies), people in Germany *were* still very sensitive about the subject. And apparently some are even now, so it is probably still best to avoid the subject.

Comment: A poster of John Cleese with title “Don’t mention the war” was hanging in the German embassy in London for years, making everyone (mostly Germans) laugh.

Answer (score 6):

Nein, gibt es nicht.

Jedes Wort kann in einer freundlichen Konversation zum Beispiel zitierend benutzt werden, notfalls mit einer vorweggeschickten Entschuldigung für das Wort, welches aber aus Gründen der Präzision genau so wiedergegeben werden muss, wie es gesagt wurde.

Zum zweiten gibt es auch in Deutschland Rassisten, und die sprechen auch untereinander oft Deutsch, so dass sie etwa das N-Wort in einer, nach allen Regeln der Psychologie freundlichen Konversation, verwenden können. Rassisten ändern nicht unbedingt ihr Vokabular, wenn sie unter sich sind.

Oder Wörterbuchautoren, die sich über die Aufnahme derartiger Wörter unterhalten - wieso sollten die unfreundlich werden?

Comment: Genial und nicht ganz richtig: " in Deutschland Rassisten, und die sprechen auch untereinander oft Deutsch," jau, aber die sind auch niemals untereinander in "polite conversation"?

Comment: Schreibe ich doch: "in freundlicher Konversation verwenden können". Oder worin besteht die Frage?

Comment: Das N-Wort galt bis vor kurzer Zeit noch als auf dem Weg ins allgemeine politische Abseits. Unter Rassisten war dieses Wort natürlich niemals verpönt. Aber der Punkt ist, dass Rassisten nach derzeit dominanter Auffassung gar keine höflichen Kommunikationsformen an den Tag legen könnten, auch nicht untereinander, eben weil es ein rassistischer Diskurs wäre. (OP-Frage war doch eher nach absoluten Kriterien, allgemein gültigen, hier kommen relative.)

Comment: @LangLangC: Kannst Du die gewagte Behauptung, dass  Rassisten nach derzeit dominanter Auffassung gar keine höflichen Kommunikationsformen an den Tag legen können, belegen? Das ist doch absoluter Humbug. Welche Klischeevorstellung von Rassisten muss man haben, um das zu glauben? Meinst Du Rassisten sind 24 h am Tag wütend und zornig? Ob jemand freundlich ist hat damit, ob er ein Rassist ist, gar nichts zu tun. Selbst wenn er auf von ihm verhasste Leute trifft kann er sich verstellen oder Ausnahmen machen usw. usf.

Comment: @userunknown: *in freundlicher Konversation* ist nicht das Gleiche wie *in polite conversation*. Das sollte man eher als *in höflicher Konversation* übersetzen

Comment: @userunknown: wenn es rassistisch ist, ist es nicht höflich, egal welche Höflichkeitsforme oder -floskeln benutzt werden. Rassismus ist selbst unhöflich.

Comment: Wieso sollten Rassisten untereinander nicht höflich miteinander umgehen können? Weil das alles ungebildetes Pack mit Schaum vor dem Mund ist? Weil Rassisten keine Menschen sind, so dass sie man sie folglich mit einem Bügelschloss aus dem Hinterhalt angreifen kann? Dass Du Rassismus selbst als unhöflich bezeichnest ist ja nicht falsch - gegenüber den Verachteten ist es natürlich unhöflich, aber wenn die bei der Kommunikation gar nicht dabei sind? Es geht nicht darum, ob Rassismus per se eine unhöfliche oder unfreundliche Sache ist, sondern ob in einer höflichen Konversation bestimmte Begriffe…

Comment: … unhöflich sind. Und was in einer Konversation höflich oder unhöflich ist, ist eine Sache, die die Teilnehmer der Konversation betrifft. Wenn Du persönlich zu Hitler gesagt hättest "Adolf, Du Mörder" wäre das, obwohl es wahr ist, unhöflich. Wenn Du eine Gruppe fanatischer Antisemiten, die wissen dass Du weißt, dass sie Antisemiten sind, mit "Schalom" begrüßt, ist das unhöflich, weil es auf den Kontext ankommt. Wenn Du bei einer streng moslemischen Familie die Frau zuerst begrüßt ist vielleicht das unhöflich (ich weiß es nicht, könnte es mir aber vorstellen).

Comment: Danke! Alles hier (Antwort und Kommentar) hilft mich auch (Aufgewertet!)...

Comment: Natürlich kann man in einer höflich-freundlichen Konversation Worte benutzen, um über diese Worte zu diskutieren. Das würden  Wörterbuchautoren sogar ganz sicher tun. Ich bezweifle auch nicht, dass Rassisten untereinander eine  freundliche Konversation führen können, in der die betreffenden Worte vorkommen und die dann genau die abwertende Bedeutung haben, um die es hier geht. Die Worte sind in diesem Fall definitiv nicht freundlich gemeint und würden m.E. nicht öffentlich geäußert werden.

Comment: @KritikerderElche: Leute, die den Begriff "N-Wort" benutzen sind offenkundig nicht der Ansicht, dass der Gebrauch des gemeinten Wortes in einem Gespräch über Sprache unbedenklich ist und ich habe schon von Fällen gehört, in denen es den Verwender den Job gekostet hat, obwohl es Metasprache war. Leider kann ich jetzt nicht mit einem Link dienen, war in den USA m.W., evtl. GB. Die Frage war "never be used in polite conversation" und dazu gehören auch Konversationen die niemand belauscht, der die Ansichten nicht teilt. Ich glaube es gibt niemanden, der über Abwesende immer so spricht, dass …

Comment: … diese das als höflich empfinden. Bedenkt man die Möglichkeit von Aufzeichnung mit, dann gilt diese hohe Hürde ja auch für alle zukünftigen Leser oder Hörer der Konversation. Vor 100 Jahren hätte niemand Anstoß an der Bezeichnung "Fräulein" genommen. Höflichkeit bemisst sich nicht an hypothetischen Zuhörern mit einwandfreiem demokratischen Leumund sondern konkret an den Teilnehmern des Gesprächs bzw. wirklichen Hörern oder Lesern.

Answer (score 6):

Neger.

I grew up in Germany in the 1970's, and the word Neger didn't seem to me to have a pejorative meaning.  It was simply a word to refer to a person of African descent, much like the word Negro was in common use in the USA (at that time).
But I recall in September, 2015, that Joachim Herrmann (CSU politician), was much taken to task, and then forced to apologize, because on a TV talk show he used the word Neger to (affectionately) refer to an artist of African Descent that he really liked (Roberto Blanco).  He said something like, "das war aber ein wunderbarer Neger."  You can look that up, it was big news.  The news also called it a use of the "N-word."

So there you go: the Germans apparently now equate Neger to the American N-word, and I can assure you that it is now on the list of words never to be uttered (by white people).  Perhaps it is the only such word?

PS

But the times change... As many of you will know from USA culture, the word(s) referring to persons of African descent keep changing, revolving as they do from novel and acceptable to quaint and finally to unacceptable.  Thus in USA, over the past 50 or so years, these words have been (time-ordered) "colored", "negro", "black", "afro-american", "African-american", finally coming nearly full circle to the current "person-of-color".  What has changed other than the words?

PPS

I'll just add that the official greeting(s) given to Adolf Hitler back in the day (either "Heil!" or "Heil Hitler!") are surely VERBOTEN in German speech, if not writing.  You might utter them if you wanted to make a very offensive political statement (for example, uttering them at a police officer, in response to what you thought was a very unreasonable direction given to you).  It might even be actually illegal to utter such phrases as part of political speech!  (German law does prohibit speech which glorifies the Third Reich, and/or denies the Holocaust).

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. PLease consider rewriting your PS and PPS to include it into a complete text. So the entire thing reads as one answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody mentioned the war.

There are a few words that due to history no longer is used. Germany is missing a good word for manager/leader because the word there is: Führer is taken.

The word Kameraden went out of use after the war in many contexts as well.

[Edit]

Disclaimer: I am not German and this may not answer the quesion about words not used. This is more about certain words in certain contexts as users have pointed out in the comments. (Thanks)

Comment: (1) _Fürer_ should be _Führer_. (2) The noun _Kameraden_ is written with an initial capital letter. (3) I do not agree that these word are not used anymore. As an example, just conceive of _Truppenführer_ and _Kameraden_ at fire departments ...

Comment: Thanks, I have added your feedback. As a non-native speaker I don't use those words any more because I have experienced that it was seen as bad. But it could have been because I used the words slightly wrong.

Comment: _Nobody mentioned the war._ Actually, user LangLangC did already in his answer. And I would strongly disagree with your final paragraph that Germany was missing a good word for "friend". There are _Freunde_ or _Kumpel_, for example.

Comment: Der Führer des Fahrzeugs is a normal thung. But I am not sure I should call my Bergfuührer that is leading me on a trip "Mein Führer".

Comment: Hast Du Dich noch nie freundlich mit jemandem über Adolph Hitler unterhalten? Wieso solltest Du da nicht "der Führer" sagen? Und bei der Bundeswehr ist m.W. auch der Begriff "Kameraden" noch üblich und die sprechen auch Deutsch. Nicht zu vergessen rechte Kameradschaften.

Comment: Ich halte die (vorgeblich) neutrale Weiterverwendung von Begriffen wie "Kamerad" und "Führer" in den funktionalen Nachfolgeorganisationen der Wehrmacht, des Volkssturms, des Luftschutzbundes, etc. sehr wohl für problematisch. Denn das Führerprinzip an sich ist Teil des Problems. Unser Bild vom vernunftbegabten und mit immanentem Wert existierenden Menschen ist mit dem Konzept "bedingungsloser Gehorsam" nicht vereinbar. - Jeder Befehl muss auf seine Rechtmäßigkeit geprüft werden, bevor er ausgeführt wird. Im Zweifel muss er verweigert werden.

Answer (score -4):

Ja, naturlich.

There are rude and offensive words in every language. Of course German has them too. Basically the same words you wouldn't use to your mother in English.

And no, I am not going to write them out here for you.

Comment: 1. My mother didn't understand a word of English, so I could have used any English word in her vicinity.  2. If you don't list them so other people can rebuke that those words are not *unspeakable words* in German, it's not much of an answer, sorry...  **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯**

Comment: Granny, sister, whatever. So what you actually want is a list of rude words in German?

Comment: No, only the unspeakable ones, but it has been established already that there aren't any...

Comment: @Fabby of course there are such words but these would really not be a good fit for a list. So this answer is probably to the point. These words would not even be listed in any dictionary. See a Google search for `site:dwds.de "vulgär"` for an incomplete list of the most common words that should not to be used in a "polite" conversation like e.g. on German SE. Whoever told you that we do not have such words is wrong or does not care.